# Getting unknown property in ActiveQuery Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Hello I have been getting unknown property error in when I am not using a foreach method of getting the value of the active query instance I need help accessing it without using foreach.

Here is my current code

```
$status = SiteController::LookupStatus($_user);
  <?php if($status->status == 1): //if status == 0?>
        <?= HTML::a('<b>REMOVE</b>',
              ['site/removesubject', 'containerid' => $values['containerid']],
                                        ['class' => 'btn-danger btn-transparent' , 'data-method' => 'post']) ?>
                                      <?php else: ?>
                                        <!-- do this -->
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

I tried accessing it with `$status->status` but I am getting the error but when I use the foreach method I am successfully getting it.

Also, here is my active record

```
 public static function LookupStatus($clientid){
    return Enrollment::find()->select(['status'])->where([
      'clientid' => $clientid,
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: `Enrollment::find()->select(['status'])->where(['clientid' => $clientid,])->one()` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify one(), all() at the end of find() in your model.

```
public static function LookupStatus($clientid){
    $model = Enrollment::find()->select(['status'])
             ->where(['clientid' => $clientid,])
             ->one()
    return $model->status;
  }
```

Comment: return Enrollment::find()->select(['status'])->where(['clientid' => $clientid])->one() should be enough